# Tried redmine and trac, but none of them allows me to share milestones and bugs between projects

Tags: svn, trac, fogbugz, redmine, branch

Do you know a good alternative to redmine or trac which allows such a feature? I've also tried fogbugz, but is too poorly integrated with the svn repository browsing (and there is no sign of code review support).

Comment: What is the use case of moving milestones *between* projects? It doesn't seem to make much sense from an project-management standpoint.

Comment: consider this example: we have a complex website with a great amount of APIs, and they must be consumed by a desktop client. The website and the client are two different projects, and the milestone is the deliver of a new feature, which requires coordination between the two projects, thus the need to share bugs and milestones.

Comment: Arguably, if the two projects are tied together this closely on a regular basis, they're really components of a larger project.  YMMV.

Comment: If you want that, you should consider thinking in subprojects.

Comment: Code review with fogbugz, KILN:
http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/LearnMore.html?section=TrackReviewsWithFogBugz

I have not tested, I just read about it right now.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry but I don't think there is "a good alternative to Redmine", it's good useable system.

I'm not too sure what exactly is driving your requirements, so my only suggestion would be to look at the sub project support on Redmine. For all your projects where you want to share bugs and milestones set up a top level project, the individual projects can then be sub projects under this main umbrella project.

If an issue is common to many projects then create it in the top project, issues specific to one project then create it in a sub project, the filtering at the top level can be set to display all the issues from the sub projects as well as the main project.

Redmine has unique numbering for all issues so in the tickets or the wiki you can cross reference tickets across projects quite easily.

If that doesn't help then I think you'll be into the realms of writing your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider Trac with the [Ticket Mover plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketMoverPlugin), which also allows the copy or move of tickets and other Trac elements, including milestones.

Not a perfect solution, as you need to migrate edits to the milestones, but we've found it useful in a situation similar to yours where milestones were distinct, but bugs/features occasionally required resolution across multiple projects.